# 400 Bad Request without any more details when forwarding logs to Opensearch via Firelens

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, firelens

I am using Firelens with Fargate to forward logs to an OpenSearch cluster (in the same VPC) as the Fargate task. Here's my configuration:

```
                "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
                "options": {
                    "Aws_Auth": "On",
                    "Aws_Region": "us-east-1",
                    "Buffer_Size": "False",
                    "HTTP_Passwd": "MY_OPEN_SEARCH_PASSWORD",
                    "HTTP_User": "masteruser",
                    "Host": "vpc-fake-domain-dmgfndgjdfgdfe.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com",
                    "Index": "logstash-*",
                    "Logstash_Format": "On",
                    "Match": "*",
                    "Name": "opensearch",
                    "Port": "443",
                    "Replace_Dots": "On",
                    "Suppress_Type_Name": "On",
                    "Trace_Error": "On",
                    "Trace_Output": "On",
                    "Type": "_doc",
                    "tls": "On",
                    "tls.verify": "Off"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            }
```

Even though I've Trace_Error set to On, I am not getting any details on the issue other than:

```
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

This appears to be a generic 400 HTTP error page that Fluent bit appears to be receiving. Is there a way for me to find out what exactly is causing this?

Here's the trace output for the request:

```
{"create":{"_index":"logstash-2023.09.15"}}
{"@timestamp":"2023-09-15T22:17:40.548Z","source":"stdout","log":"10.0.44.164 - - [15/Sep/2023:22:17:40 +0000] Log Message","container_id":"5a23495fc387471e858b8b0be1b3d57a-2521534270","container_name":"bundle-web","ecs_cluster":"fargate-cluster","ecs_task_arn":"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXX:task/fargate-cluster/XXXXXX","ecs_task_definition":"dev-bundle-web:37"}
```